# Android Statement Sqlite Cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have source code like this :

```
if (proses == 3) {
    HistoryConnector dbkonek = new HistoryConnector(this);
    dbkonek.open();

    //CURSOR air
    cursorSumberAir = dbkonek.getOneDataSumberAir(rowId);
    cursorKegunaanAir = dbkonek.getOneDataKegunaanAir(rowId);
    cursorSifatAir = dbkonek.getOneDataSifatAir(rowId);
    cursorPerlakuanAir = dbkonek.getOneDataPerlakuanAir(rowId);
    cursorPenyimpananAir = dbkonek.getOneDataPenyimpananAir(rowId);
    cursorSanitasi = dbkonek.getOneDataSanitasi(rowId);
    cursorSumberAir.moveToFirst();
    cursorKegunaanAir.moveToFirst();
    cursorSifatAir.moveToFirst();
    cursorPerlakuanAir.moveToFirst();
    cursorPenyimpananAir.moveToFirst();
    cursorSanitasi.moveToFirst();
} else {  
    DatabaseConnector dbkonek = new DatabaseConnector(this); 
    dbkonek.open();

    //CURSOR air
    cursorSumberAir = dbkonek.getOneDataSumberAir(rowId);
    cursorKegunaanAir = dbkonek.getOneDataKegunaanAir(rowId);
    cursorSifatAir = dbkonek.getOneDataSifatAir(rowId);
    cursorPerlakuanAir = dbkonek.getOneDataPerlakuanAir(rowId);
    cursorPenyimpananAir = dbkonek.getOneDataPenyimpananAir(rowId);
    cursorSanitasi = dbkonek.getOneDataSanitasi(rowId);
    cursorSumberAir.moveToFirst();
    cursorKegunaanAir.moveToFirst();
    cursorSifatAir.moveToFirst();
    cursorPerlakuanAir.moveToFirst();
    cursorPenyimpananAir.moveToFirst();
    cursorSanitasi.moveToFirst();
}
```

I want this: If `proses == 3` then `dbkonek` create new `HistoryConnector`. else `dbkonek` create new `DatabaseConnector`, how I could achieve this?
Because when I make source like this:

```
if (proses == 3) {
    HistoryConnector dbkonek = new HistoryConnector(this);
    dbkonek.open();
} else {  
    DatabaseConnector dbkonek = new DatabaseConnector(this); 
    dbkonek.open();
}
    //CURSOR air
    cursorSumberAir = dbkonek.getOneDataSumberAir(rowId);
    cursorKegunaanAir = dbkonek.getOneDataKegunaanAir(rowId);
    cursorSifatAir = dbkonek.getOneDataSifatAir(rowId);
    cursorPerlakuanAir = dbkonek.getOneDataPerlakuanAir(rowId);
    cursorPenyimpananAir = dbkonek.getOneDataPenyimpananAir(rowId);
    cursorSanitasi = dbkonek.getOneDataSanitasi(rowId);
    cursorSumberAir.moveToFirst();
    cursorKegunaanAir.moveToFirst();
    cursorSifatAir.moveToFirst();
    cursorPerlakuanAir.moveToFirst();
    cursorPenyimpananAir.moveToFirst();
    cursorSanitasi.moveToFirst();
```

edited, any one connector like this:

```
public class DatabaseConnector {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "DataAssessment.db";
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DatabaseOpenHelper dbOpenHelper;

    public DatabaseConnector(Context context) {
        dbOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    }
}
```

source code above, `dbkonek` cannot detect in cursor. how i can be simple this source code.
Thanks for advance

Comment: Too much code (more than needed), foreign language, overall a really unclear question... What is it that you need to do?

Comment: i want dbkonek reference to new class HistoryConnect or DatabaseConnector,

First i must be declare variable dbkonek,
how i can declare dbkonek. before statement.

Comment: I see, do `HistoryConnector` and `DatabaseConnector` share a _base class_ or an _interface_ ?

Comment: MyConnector is HistoryConnector and DatabaseConnector, i have two database, and i have two Connector, first is HistoryConnector and two is DatabaseConnector, if proses == 3 then create History Connector, else create DatabaseConnector, my question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class hierarchy has to be designed such that `HistoryConnector` and `DatabaseConnector` share a common *base class* or *interface*, presumably called `Connector`, that defines the set of operations that are available on *any* type of *Connector*. Then you would simply do:

```
Connector dbkonek;
if(proses == 3){
    dbkonek = new HistoryConnector(this);
}else{  
    dbkonek = new DatabaseConnector(this);
}
dbkonek.open();
...
```